# gRPC use of Lists in protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having a `List<MyClass>` on my server-side and want to get it to my clients using gRPC.
`MyClass` looks like the following:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public long Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I define this list in protobuf and in which way am I supposed to override the generated method?

My .proto looks currently like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
 
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

service MyService {
    rpc GetValues(EmptyRequest) returns (MyResponse);
}

message EmptyRequest{
}

message MyResponse{
    repeated int64 values = 1;
    repeated google.protobuf.Timestamp time = 2;
    repeated string name = 3;
}
```

Comment: I'd advise a similar construction to this: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other i.e. wrap MyResponse into a new message under a repeated field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root message is singular (unless you're using streaming), so you would typically create a separate message that *has* a list/repeated set of `MyClass`.

If you're using .proto, this might be:

```
service MyService {
    rpc GetValues(EmptyRequest) returns (MyResponse);
}

message EmptyRequest{
}

message MyResponse {
    repeated MyClass items = 1;
}
message MyClass {
    int64 values = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp time = 2;
    string name = 3;
}
```

Note that you may also want to use [empty.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/empty.proto) rather than your own. Finally, note that if you're using protobuf-net.Grpc, you can skip the .proto step entirely and just use your own POCOs